# Nested integral takes too long with NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I am attempting to calculate a nested multiple integral. The code snippet is given by

```
 i1[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_?NumericQ] := i1[x1, x2, x3, x4] = 
 NIntegrate[(x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5))^4/( 
   x2 x3 x4 x5 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5) + 
    x1 x3 x4 x5 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5) + 
    x1 x2 x4 x5 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5) + 
    x1 x2 x3 x5 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5) + 
    x1 x2 x3 x4 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5) + 
    x1 x2 x3 x4 x5)^6, {x5, 0, 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4}];

i2[x1_, x2_, x3_?NumericQ] :=i2[x1, x2, x3] = 
 NIntegrate[i1[x1, x2, x3, x4], {x4, 0, 1 - x1 - x2 - x3}];

i3[x1_, x2_?NumericQ] := i3[x1, x2] = NIntegrate[i2[x1, x2, x3], {x3, 0, 1 - x1 - x2}];

i4[x1_?NumericQ] := i4[x1] = NIntegrate[i3[x1, x2], {x2, 0, 1 - x1}];
NIntegrate[i4[x1], {x1, 0, 1}]
```

However this seems to take way too long (I even left it overnight and it had not been evaluated). Can anyone help me to get around this issue?

Comment: This `NIntegrate[(x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 (1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5))^4/(x2 x3 x4 x5 (1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5)+x1 x3 x4 x5 (1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5)+x1 x2 x4 x5 (1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5)+x1 x2 x3 x5 (1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5)+x1 x2 x3 x4 (1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5)+x1 x2 x3 x4 x5)^6,{x1,0,1},{x2,0,1-x1},{x3,0,1-x1-x2},{x4,0,1-x1-x2-x3},{x5,0,1-x1-x2-x3-x4},Method->"MultidimensionalRule",PrecisionGoal->3]` gives an answer, but also error messages ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct approach, bypassing `NIntegrate`:

```
(* Gauss-Kronrod rule abscissae, weights, and error weights *)
{abs, wts, err} = 
  Developer`ToPackedArray /@ 
   NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[21, MachinePrecision];

(* integrand evaluations *)
data =
   With[{i = (
           (x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5))^4/
             (x2 x3 x4 x5 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5) +
                x1 x3 x4 x5 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5) +
                x1 x2 x4 x5 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5) +
                x1 x2 x3 x5 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5) +
                x1 x2 x3 x4 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5) +
                x1 x2 x3 x4 x5)^6 //
            # (1 - x1) (1 - x1 - x2) (1 - x1 - x2 - x3) *
               (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4) &
           ) /. x5 -> xj (1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4) /.
         x4 -> x4 (1 - x1 - x2 - x3) /.
        x3 -> x3 (1 - x1 - x2) /.
       x2 -> x2 (1 - x1)},
    Compile[{{xj, _Real, 1}, {x4, _Real}},
      Table[i, {x1, xj}, {x2, xj}, {x3, xj}],
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
      ][abs, abs]
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {4.68719, Null}  *)

(* integral *)
Nest[#.wts &, data, 5]
(*  0.00835538  *)

(* error estimate: ~4 digits of precision *)
Nest[#.err &, data, 5]
(*  3.43986*10^-6  *)
```